# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rango'

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use Python shell to import a model, getting error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rango'

- I've also noticed in my urls.py i am getting 'Unresolved Import:
  views'
- I think my project structure might be the cause of both errors, I
  used eclipse to create django project for the first time.
- I have added rango app in the installed apps in setting, just as: `'rango',`

**HERE IS THE SCREEN FOR PROJECT STRUCTURE AND ERROR: https://i.stack.imgur.com/moLAS.jpg**

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render

from django.http import HttpResponse

def index(request):
    context_dict = {'boldmessage': "Crunchy, creamy, cookie, candy, cupcake!" }
    return render(request, 'rango/index.html', context=context_dict)
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Category(models.Model):
    # Unique TRUE attr means the name must be unique - can be used as a primary key too!
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return models.Model.__str__(self)

class Page(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    url = models.URLField()
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return models.Model.__str__(self)

class user_session(models.Model):
    userNAME = models.CharField(max_length=120, unique=True)
    addToCarts = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self): 
        # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.headlin
```

Comment: which directory are the urls.py that you are trying to import the views

Comment: try `from ..rango import views`

Comment: In the photo, you can see there are two urls.py, one is rango app, and the other file is in Tango folder. Both files urls.py show error. Is that what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

if your `urls.py` are in the same folder with `views.py` you can try it

```
from . import views
```

but if the `urls.py` are in the Tango folder try

```
from ..rango import views
```

also can you try to rename you first `Tango` folder, here can came error

```
Tango/
    Tango/
        ...
        rongo/
        Tango/
        ...
```

try to rename first Tango folder to be something like this

```
Projects/
    Tango/
        ...
        rongo/
        Tango/
        ...
```

Comment: okay .. rango worked. does .. mean that go back to directories? Also importantly the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rango'  is still there when importing model in shell? ideas?

Comment: `..` represent parent directory

Comment: Okay makes sense! any idea about the ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'rango' in shell?

Comment: can you edit you answer and put there all traceback ?

Comment: i update my answer, can you try to rename the first Tango folder ?

Comment: Okay renamed project folder to project, and the trackback pydev_import_hook.py, here https://imgur.com/a/WlfNzEN

Comment: Any ideas? please